# How to Compare Response with value in postman Test cases

Tags: javascript, postman, testcase

I have made a get request in postman which will return some response. I would like to compare that response has the value > 0 in test cases.

My current code is

```
  pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.default_project_id) > 10
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the json response, please ? which failure message do you have ?

Comment: I am not getting any error but the test case is passing for any number like if I compare with 100000 also it's showing success.

Comment: I haven't gone through Chai functions use deeply so I'm not fully familiar with it but I guess that there must be some 'literal' way of comparing your value. If you look at Chai's functions (you can find the link with postman API) you may find the 'above' method to be useful. Doing something like pm.expect(jsonData.default_project_id).to.be.above(10). Else don't use Chai notation and do basic javascript assertions, it may be less 'user readable' but much more straightforward ...

Comment: here is the link. http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_above

Answer (score 2):

In the test section you can use the assert nodeJS module:

```
var assert = require('assert');

pm.test("The default ID > 10", function () {
    assert(jsonData.default_project_id > 10);
});
```

keep in mind that the default_project_id should be a number